# Numbers of ways of Rendering in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, render

Can anyone please tell me how many ways are there to render a screen in Qt.Like Show() , QDirectPainter etc...

Comment: why does it matter how many ways there are? If I said "6" would anything change for you? perhaps a better question would "could you list the known methods?"

Answer (score 1):

Qt is double buffered. So, you would use update() to request a screen redraw. Another perspective would be to enumerate the backends in Qt - and this varies on different platforms. E.g. for Windows you can use raster, OpenGL or Direct3D. In Qt 4.5 a new graphics system is introduced, where you can specify that *all* rendering should be done using one of native, raster, opengl. See also [So Long and Thanks for the Blit!](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/10/22/so-long-and-thanks-for-the-blit/)